# Rails - product database model for multiple price types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm looking for recommendations about how I should go about this :

I have `products` that have **multiple prices** (ex: Infant: 5€, Child: 10€, Adult: 15€).

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.integer "adult_price_cents"
  t.integer "child_price_cents"
  t.integer "infant_price_cents"
  ...
end
```

Now, I want for some products to have a **single price** (ex: 45€) (so no **multiple prices** as stated above)

- Should I just create a new column called `single_price_cents` and check everytime I need if it has a single price ?
- Or should I add as well a `product_type` column that would store if it's a single_price product or a multi_price product ?
- Or should I do it totally differently than the two options above ?

Thanks in advance for your time and help  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're cramming too much into a single model / table. And it would be better to setup a join table instead of swelling the number of columns as the complexity grows.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :variants
end

# rails g model variant name:string price:decimal product:belongs_to
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

This avoids creating a bunch of columns in the table which contain mostly nulls.

You can then check if a product has variants and use the base price otherwise:

```
<h1><%= @product.name %></h1>
<% if @product.variants.any? %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <% @product.variants.each do |v| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= v.name %></td>
      <td><%= v.price %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% else %>
  <h2><%= @product.price %></h2>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You're right, I should probably separate it into a dedicated table. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

In case a `product` may have single or multiple `price`, it's better if you separate price to a single model with two-column is `price` and `type` with using [enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) , associate with the product model, one product can have one or more price, I think it's better to manage or change latter.